# Can I use j and k to navigate search results in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Is it possible to override the up and down arrow keys and use j and k to traverse IntelliJ search result windows?

For example Find In Path (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), Find References (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>), and many more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related request:

- [IDEA-108609](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108609) Cannot remap cursor keys for navigation outside the editor (popups, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can navigate with alt-key using a plugin. You can use alt-i, alt-k and so on.

Look this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9852-ijkl-shortctus

Github page: https://github.com/dkandalov/ijkl-shortcuts-plugin